# Google play turnbased game getting status code 6001 when I invite a friend

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

```
public static final int STATUS_MULTIPLAYER_ERROR_NOT_TRUSTED_TESTER

The user attempted to invite another user who was not authorized to see the game. This can occur if a trusted tester invites a user who is not a trusted tester while the game is unpublished. In this case, the invitations will not be sent.

Constant Value: 6001 (0x00001771)
```

I don't know why I am getting this. In the google play developer console I have added the person I am inviting as a tester. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think it is a timing/caching problem. Try again after some time has elapsed since you added the user as a tester, giving the change time to propagate to all servers in the cloud. And double check the email of the tester.

Answer (score 0):

I known the question is old, but I get the issue today.

In the Google Play Console Test section, my tester switch is checked but I have to add my testers manually, it seems it doesn't take into account my tester list (from alpha/beta).